# How can I access data from before the last 30 days on Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

Google Analytics' maximum date range seems to be last 30 days. There is 0 chance this is actually the maximum viewable age of data, given how crucial it is for webmasters to compare current data to older data...right? How can I view data from an arbitrary time ago?

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics does not have a 30 day limitation.  You can choose a "custom" date range and choose whatever start and end you want over any time period.

[image: 3 month Google Analytics custom date range]

I personally think that the limited selection of dates available in the drop down is severely lacking.   I use a [custom page of date options for Google analytics](https://ostermiller.org/calc/ga.html) that I created to link to a wider variety of time periods.

[image: Custom Google Analytics date ranges]